# Is there an auto compiler in rails importmap-rails when you have changes in javascript? (like in webpacker or esbuild)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, importmap-rails

I have a new rails project which by default has a importmap.

For updating my changes i need to every time type

```
rails assets:precompile
```

but i know in webpacker they will be recompiling with your changes. Is there possible to do same in importmaps?

Just imported one package and do small javascript controller using stimulus

Comment: You should not precompile your assets in development, only when deploying to production

Comment: @BroiSatse then it isnt to update my changes in /javascript folder

Comment: you need to remove precompiled assets `bin/rails assets:clobber`. there is no compiler, everything runs in the browser as is.

Answer (score 1):

how @Alex says -

```
rake assets:clobber     # Remove compiled assets
```

that command helps me, thanks you Alex!